# Why is my kali linux installation not showing in the bios

Tags: kali-linux, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot Kali Linux and Windows on two separate physical drives.

But, after I go through the installation process for Kali it just goes back to the BIOS and does not show up in the boot priority menu.

I have disabled secure boot but it still does not work. I have even tried taking the Windows drive out of my PC.

In Windows, the Linux system shows up in disk management like this:
[image: Linux System Partitions]

I also installed Kali Linux on the same disk as my Windows install and it worked fine but I still want to install it separate from my Windows install.

Comment: Is the "`BOOT`" flag set on the Kali partition?

Comment: I presume you got it installed by booting an live / installation medium (e.g. USB drive), right? Can you boot to it again and run `sudo efibootmgr` and add the output to your question? If possible, also try to mount the first partition of the `Disk 3` there (with `sudo mount -r /dev/sdX1 /mnt`) and list the content inside (with `tree /mnt` or `ls -lR /mnt`) and add the output to your question as well. (`sudo lsblk -f` might help you identify which `sdX` is `Disk 3`. It may not necessarily be `sdd`.) (It might also be some `nvmeNn1p1` instead of `sdX1`.)

Comment: @waltinator What is the boot flag?

Comment: @TomYan I did install it using a usb drive but I never got into the OS. Is there a different way to enter the commands. Or is there a different version of kali where you can boot live from the drive.

Comment: There's the live boot version: https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-platforms (I thought the install image also offer a live environment like Fedora and Ubuntu; apparently I was wrong?)

Comment: Ok thanks, if I can't figure it out I might try to use that.

Comment: @waltinator The presence of an `EFI System Partition` indicates UEFI-style booting, and the "`BOOT` flag on the Kali partition" is applicable only to BIOS-style booting.